# Are these stunted fronds on my date palm?

Tags: pruning, palm

[image]

When my date palm was installed it had a few of these things around the edge of the trunk. Are they stunted fronds? Should I remove them? The palm itself is healthy and appears to be growing well.

[image]

Comment: How long since you had the plant installed?

Comment: About 10 weeks.

Answer (score 1):

I have a date palm I grew from pits and sometimes see this.  The fronds open up and look fine after a while.  Just keep up with your normal watering if it is dry as I find date palms are thirsty